# Prediction quantiles intersect from gradient-boosted regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I am trying to build a regressor model that takes in various types of product and market information, applies transformations to the data, and predicts a price for the product at regular intervals throughout the day. I'd like to be able to predict quantile confidence bands, to help my team make decisions based on the model's predictions. I have followed the methodology in [`this example from the scikit-learn documentation`](https://scikit-learn.org/1.3/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_gradient_boosting_quantile.html), but I've found that the predictions produced by these regressors sometimes intersect, e.g. sometimes the P50 prediction is greater than the P75 prediction or less than the P25 prediction.

[See errors in graph highlighted here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAzKR.png)

This problem persists even with wider bands, including P95 and P05. I've been able to reproduce the linked example without issues, although the dataset is much simpler than the one I'm using.

The code below represents a reproducible example for the problem, with a generated dataset:

```py
# Imports and definitions
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import HistGradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

X,y = make_regression(
    n_samples = 14000,
    n_features = 39,
    n_targets = 1
)

# Making test/train split and models dict
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.1
)
models = {}

for alpha in [0.25, 0.5, 0.75]:    # HistGradientBoostingRegressor model - early_stopping = False helps issue, but doesn't solve it
    hgbr = HistGradientBoostingRegressor(
        max_iter=100, # Usually around 1000, reduced for example
        loss="quantile",
        quantile = alpha,
    )

    # Add best model to dict
    models[f"P{alpha*100:02.0f}"] = hgbr.fit(X_train, y_train.ravel())
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Reduced code example to be more minimal